# Nginx rewrite individual urls with get parameters to pretty urls

Tags: nginx

I have categories I'd like to rewrite.
for example:

example.com/videos?c=18

to:

example.com/category/name

I tried to do this using multiple examples, most had no effect and this example gave me only page not found to all /videos pages:

```
location  /videos {
if ($args ~ "c=18") {
rewrite ^/videos(.*) http://$server_name/category/name$1 permanent;
}
}
```

Is this even doable purely via Nginx what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this the "pretty" URL you actually have on the site or the one you want to have? `example.com/videos?c=18`

Comment: That's what I have on the site now: example.com/videos?c=18 and I want to change it to example.com/category/nameofthecategory

Comment: So you'd like instead of `example.com/videos?c=18` to have `example.com/videos/18` ?

Comment: No :). Let's say c=18 category includes cars. So i'd like to have example.com/category/cars or example.com/videos/cars instead of get parameter

Comment: You can only rewrite pieces that are already in the url. Don't see `cars` there.

Comment: Well, that's what I was asking all along in the original question mate. Is it even possible what I tried to achieve ;).

Comment: Well, the question was about rewriting, that is dynamic conversion of urls. And you can only rewrite what's in url already. Otherwise it's hardcoding.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Have to do it on the code side of the things in that case then if it's not doable via nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I got the question, currently your site has this url scheme, which you can't change:

```
http://example.com/videos?c=18
```

But you would like to present visitors with "pretty"-looking URLs like

```
http://example.com/category/name
```

That pretty URL does not *really* exist anywhere on the site, which is why you have to *rewrite it*, e.g. turn pretty virtual url into a real one that your scripts can process.

Once again, you rewrite *from* virtual *to* actual, not the other way round.

The following directive would turn `/category/cars/` into `/videos?c=cars`

```
location /category {
    rewrite ^/category/(.*)$ /videos?c=$1 last;
}
```

But your script won't understand `/videos?c=cars` url, it needs category ID to work. So in your case the pretty url should look like

```
http://example.com/category/18
```

which will be rewritten to

```
http://example.com/videos?c=18
```

Comment: Works for me as well! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"if" directive is not best solution, but in your case you can try "if" and $arg_name (argument name in the request line):

```
location /videos {
  if ($arg_c = "18") {
    rewrite ^/videos(.*) http://$server_name/category/cars? permanent;
  }
  if ($arg_c = "19") {
    rewrite ^/videos(.*) http://$server_name/category/bikes? permanent;
  }
  # and so on
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a go.